# Two git users using the same local repository

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

We have two developers who need to access local Git repository on our server. We have both very limited experience with Git and we just started using it in our team. We have two separate Bitbucket accounts with all necessary permissions. We both use the same admin account on our server, which we access via ssh. We want to be able to use our own Bitbucket accounts to manage Git repo on the server, but we don't know how to do this. We've tried putting something like:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://user1@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "origin2"]
        url = https://user2@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin2/*
[branch "dev"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/dev
```

in `.git/config`, and now user1 can work as usual and user2 has to do e.g. `git pull origin2`... But I'm not sure if it is the right solution, is it? Are we actually working on the same branch now? What is the recommended way to deal with such a situation?

Comment: Each user should have their own clone of the repo on their local machine.  They should not interact directly at all.

Comment: Yes, that's what we do. But then we need to pull the code to the server to test it there (which happens quite often, so both of us need access).

Comment: You would probably be best using a Continuous Integration solution like Jenkins or Bamboo then have the server automatically pull down any changes that you push to a branch that you're monitoring.

Comment: @KeifKraken yeah, maybe. But I don't think we need it for now.